# Flash CC Canvas and GSAP: How to set registration point of movieclip on stage

Tags: transform, easeljs, flash-cc, gsap

How would I go about changing the registration point of a movieclip labeled "tablet" placed on the stage (root) dynamically?

For example: I have the following:

```
var tablet = this.tablet;    //movieclip labeled "tablet" on stage
function resetTablet(){
tablet.regX = tablet.width/2; //move registration point to center
tablet.regY = tablet.height/2;
```

}

However when I call it using GSAP:

```
var tl = new TimelineLite();
tl.to(tablet, 1, {alpha:1, onComplete:resetTablet})
  .to(tablet, 3, {alpha:0, scaleX:1.5, scaleY:1.5})
```

the registration point is still set to the upper left corner rather than the center.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registration points affect change both the transformation point, but also the position. If you set a displayobject that is 100x100 pixels to `regX=50;regY=50`, then it will draw from that point, moving the content 50px to the top and left. If you make that change you should also translate the clip to `x=50;y=50`.

An issue with you example is that there is no `width` or `height` on EaselJS content ([explained here](http://blog.createjs.com/update-width-height-in-easeljs/)). You can get the bounds of anything generated by Flash CC using the `nominalBounds` property, which Flash exports as a property on every object. If you have multiple frames, you can turn on "multi-frame bounds" in the publish settings, and a `frameBounds` property is added to the objects as well.

Note that `nominalBounds` and `frameBounds` are not used by the `getBounds` method.

Here is how you might be able to approach it.

```
var bounds = tablet.nominalBounds;
tablet.regX = bounds.width/2;
tablet.regY = bounds.height/2;

// Optional if your actual registration point was [0,0] before:
tablet.x += tablet.regX;
tablet.y += tablet.regX;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am still not entirely understanding this...
So the bounds variable holds the value that results from the width and height divided by 2 to get the center for the registration point?What does this do exactly?`tablet.x += tablet.regX;`

Comment: I only got it to display correctly when adding the following to your code:`tl.set(tablet, {x:225, y:125}) .to(tablet, 6, {x:"-=145"}, "start")` 
I had to divide the width and height of my displayObject "tablet" manually in order to set the initial x and y position, how would I be able to dynamically generate the changed x and y position resulting from the change in setting the registration point?

Comment: I was just offsetting the image by the amount that it is translated when you change the regX/regY